# nginx - missing etag when gzip is used

Tags: http, nginx, gzip, etag

If I setup nginx to use gzip, it removes any etag header.

The reasoning behind this is that the same resource cannot be byte-for-byte identical given that gzip has various compression levels.

But nginx also removes a weak etag, which just means that the resources are semantically equivalent. This seems like incorrect behavior by nginx.

Am I missing something? If not, is there a way to fix this?

[wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_ETag#Strong_and_weak_validation)

Comment: What the config and what version of nginx do you use?

Comment: nginx 1.6. In config I have gzip=on and etag=on. If I change to gzip=off, then etag works.

Comment: You should upgrade to [nginx 1.7.3](https://allmychanges.com/p/soft/nginx/#1.7.3) or higher. `Feature: weak entity tags are now preserved on response modifications, and strong ones are changed to weak.`

Comment: Oh wow, thanks. I am not sure why I assumed that 1.6 is the latest. why not post your comment as an answer?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You should upgrade to nginx 1.7.3 or higher.

> Feature: weak entity tags are now preserved on response modifications, and strong ones are changed to weak.