# can not set etag header on nginx

Tags: php, nginx

I was using Nginx1.4.6 when I realized that I have to set `gzip off;`to be able to set the ETag header with php.
After reading [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31125888/nginx-missing-etag-when-gzip-is-used)
I did an upgrade to Nginx 1.10.1 using chef. I added the repository to the apt cookbook with

```
apt_repository 'nginx-php' do
    uri          'ppa:nginx/stable'
    distribution node['lsb']['codename']
end
```

And then upgraded nginx with:

```
package 'nginx' do
   action :upgrade
end
```

But everything seems to be same as with the older nginx version.
Only if I explicitly set `gzip off;` I can set the ETag header.

Also I did not see the `etag on;` directive in my nginx.conf file and setting it manually did not have any effect.

It could be that I just need to do a `vagrant destroy` and `vagrant provision` again - but I think I am missing something here.

**UPDATE:**
I got it working now after detroying the machine again and also deleting the `.vagrant` folder. But I am not shure if that was the problem.
Now I can set ETag headers and the Request contains the `If-None-Match` header. But my Etags get translated into weak Etags and nginx prepends a `W/` before the hash. Is this the default behaviour ? and how can I set strong Etags ?

**UPDATE:**
Alright because of gzip on; the etag is weak ...is there no way to set a strong etag with gzip enabled ?

Comment: Do you see the nginx executable actually get upgraded as expected? If so, please remove the `chef` tag as this is unrelated to Chef.

Comment: Well it must -when I do `nginx -v` it tells me `nginx version: nginx/1.10.1`.
I also destroyed the vmbox and was setting it up again to make shure there are no remnants of the older nginx version - but still the same problem.

Comment: Try killing all stale workers, after reload they may still linger for some time due to keepalives/websockets

Comment: I am no networking / server expert - can you tell me how to do that ? I was thinking vagrant destroy destroys everything ?

Answer (score 1):

Answering my own question.

A strong Etag (with php) is set when using

`ob_start('ob_gzhandler')`

before headers are sent.